# is there any method available for change the property "right align text" of CListBox in MFC(c++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, clistbox

I am working on Microsoft Foundation Class (c++)chat application in which i want to show client message on right side of the list box,There is a property available "Right align text" but i want to do it by method. because default Left side text is also necessary for me.

Thank You.

Comment: show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ModifyStyleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf6zed6.aspx) to add/remove the [extended style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) `WS_EX_RIGHT` as required, e.g. to right-align:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1)->ModifyStyleEx(NULL, WS_EX_RIGHT);
```